# How To Fix undefined method `product' for #<LineItem::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000017b22f70>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm try product quantity - 1 but ı get this error

line_item.rb

```
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product
```

payment.rb

```
has_many :orders
```

undefined method `product' for # LineItem::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000017b22f70>

```
@line_item = LineItem.where(:order_id => params[:zc_orderid])
        @line_item.product.quantity = @line_item.product.quantity - 1
        if @line_item.product.quantity == 0
          @line_item.product.sold = true
        end
        @line_item.product.save
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your code in a transaction in order to make the changes atomic.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ calling unbanged `ActiveRecord::Base#save` without checking the outcome is a very dangerous practice.

Comment: That `sold` field seems redundant. You could simply check if `quantity` is above zero instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Order` has many `LineItem` you should expect more than one line, so should rewrite your code:

```rb
LineItem.where(:order_id => params[:zc_orderid]).each do |line_item|
  product = line_item.product
  product.quantity -= 1
  if product.quantity == 0
    product.sold = true
  end
  product.save
end
```

Btw, consider add a [Transaction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-transaction).

Comment: does not decrease the quantity of any product

Comment: @Stefan, sorry, fixed :)

Comment: @MansurBerbero I missed `each` , sorry. Now it's fixed

Answer (score 3):

If you use `where`, you don't get a single `LineItem` object, but a `LineItem::ActiveRecord_Relation` object. If that condition is enough to get just one record then use `find_by`. If it's not you need to think more about the logic because you'd get more than one object.

```
@line_item = LineItem.find_by(:order_id => params[:zc_orderid])
```

If you want to decrease the quantity of all those line items I'd do something like

```
LineItem.transaction do
  LineItem.where(:order_id => params[:zc_orderid]).each do |line_item|
    line_item.product.quantity = line_item.product.quantity - 1
    if line_item.product.quantity == 0
      line_item.product.sold = true
    end
    line_item.product.save
  end
end
```

Comment: However, if more than one product is saled, only the first product quantity falls

Comment: which is the `first product`?

Comment: Although `find_by` fixes the error, it probably doesn't solve the OP's problem (decreasing the quantity of the ordered products).

Comment: @Ursus you are a gift of god to me

Comment: Thanks @MansurBerbero, way too nice :)

Answer (score 0):

`LineItem.where(:order_id => params[:zc_orderid])` its return as array format.

So you can fetch by following
`LineItem.find_by(order_id: params[:zc_orderid])`. its return single active record

Comment: @MansurBerbero order id is unique right?.  then why do u use where?

Comment: @MansurBerbero one order belongs to an product. if it sold means u reduce a count in product right?

Comment: `@line_item = LineItem.find_by(order_id: params[:zc_orderid])
        @line_item.product.quantity = @line_item.product.quantity - 1
        if @line_item.product.quantity == 0
          @line_item.product.sold = true
        end
        @line_item.product.save`

Comment: @VeluDhanesh an order can have more than one line item. `find_by` only fetches the first one.

Comment: Then loop @lime_items and fetch product then reduce it count